# Transition is working not working on Safari

Tags: css, safari, transition

A car who dives in 4 sec from the left to the right of a div. 
It works on all browsers except on safari.

What should I do to make it work on safari?

```
#left {
    padding-top: 6px;
    height: 19px;
    width: 45px;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    right: 90%;
    transition: right 4s ease-in;
    -webkit-transition: right 4s ease-in;
}
#right {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: white;
    background-image: url('img/paal_sprite.gif');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: 0px 0;
    transition: background-position 0s linear 4s;
    -webkit-transition: background-position 0s linear 4s;
    width: 10px;
    height: 30px;
}
#left.animate {
    right: +20px;
}
#right.animate {
    background-position: -12px 0; 
}
#container {
    position: relative;
    overflow:hidden;
    height: 25px;
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: can you add jsFiddle for see the code on action pls ?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Bqnd9/3/ this effect ? i check why on safari it doesnt work

Comment: Hmm, when i remove % for .animate and i put px, this works on safari.

Comment: But then is not responsive.

Answer (score 1):

For Safari, you need to put `XXpx with XXpx`, and XX% with XX%.

For this work you need change `#left.animate +20px by +XX%;`

```
#left.animate {
    right: 20%;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bqnd9/5/)

Answer (score 0):

In **Safari 5.1** (Windows) i had to put all timings in **ms**. At least fot background-color property to work.

```
-webkit-transition: all 300ms linear;
```